# Inserting value when there is no value in second arraylist

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I've got a problem which takes up a lot of time. While it's supposed to be really easy (because it's just so simple!).
My problem:
I have these values inside two arraylists:

```
$row[0]->COUNTER1          20     10     15
$row[0]->GRADE_POINTS      0      3      5
```

I am supposed to change these arraylists into this example:

```
$row[0]->COUNTER1          20    0      0     10    0     15
$row[0]->GRADE_POINTS      0     1      2     3     4     5
```

So the missing values are supposed to have 0 as the counter.
While this isn't that hard to do it I'm probably over thinking it.

The code which I use to create the first set of numbers is:

```
$result = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresult);

$xml = $result->children("soapenv", true)->Body->children();
$xmlBody = $xml[0];
$countPerResultaat = array();
foreach($xmlBody->query[0] as $row)
{ 
  $countPerResultaat[] = (int) $row[0]->COUNTER1;
  $xaxis[] = (string) $row[0]->GRADE_POINTS;
}
```

The code I though that would work is this:

```
for($i; $i<=10; $i++){
//foreach($xmlBody->query[0] as $row)
//{ 

    $row = $xmlBody->query[0];

    if($i==$row[0]->GRADE_POINTS){
        $countPerResultaat[] = (int) $row[0]->COUNTER1;
        $xaxis[] = (string) $row[0]->GRADE_POINTS;
    }else{
        $xaxis[] = (string) $i;
        $countPerResultaat[] = (int) 0;
    }

}
```

But the row can't be used, I really don't know how to fix this. My only solution would be to use another for-loop, which would create 100 values probably.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and if `$row[0]->COUNTER1` and `$row[0]->GRADE_POINTS` are arrays. You will just need to loop them and use `in_array()`. Consider this example:

```
$counter1 = array(20, 10, 15);
$grade_points = array(0, 3, 5);
$new_grade_points = range(min($grade_points), max($grade_points));
foreach($new_grade_points as $key => &$value) {
    // check if its part of the missing index if not get the value,
    // if its the missing index put 0
    $value = (in_array($key, $grade_points)) ? array_shift($counter1) : 0;
}

$counter1 = array_values($new_grade_points); // now contains 20,0,0,10,0,15
$grade_points = array_keys($new_grade_points); // now contains 0,1,2,3,4,5

print_r($counter1);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 15
)
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me. It's a shame PHP doesn't have native error logging... However the $row[0]->COUNTER1 and $row[0]->GRADE_POINTS are coming from a XML object, like I editted in the question first piece of code. Can you help me with that? It looks like your sollution is very close, but not yet the real solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count the amount of times a grade has been given? You should just loop through as usual, and when there is no value you should/could define it as `0`. After that just count how many duplicates you have in the array. That way the key of the `$xaxis` is the grade, and the value is the amount of times that grade has been given.

```
foreach($xmlBody->query[0] as $row)
{ 
    $counter = (int) $row[0]->COUNTER1;

    if(counter) $countPerResultaat[] = $counter;
    else $countPerResultaat[] = 0; 
}

$xaxis = array_count_values($counter);
```